# Changing single column data with multiple rows to multiple column data with single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query is :

```
SELECT TOP 2 trans_date_np FROM day_in_status_mcg ORDER BY day_in_id DESC
```

Result :

```
2070÷10÷02  ->row 1
2070÷10÷01  ->row 2
```

Can I get result like this :

```
column 1       column 2
2070÷10÷02     2070÷10÷02
```

I tried to use XML PATH.
'trans_date_np' is varchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how many rows you have you can use the pivot statement.

```
SELECT [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
FROM
(SELECT TOP 5 trans_data_np, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by day_in_id) as rowNumber  
    FROM day_in_status_mcg
    ORDER BY day_in_id
    ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
min(trans_data_np)
FOR rowNumber IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: If number of rows are unknown, then how can I get desired result ?

Comment: i'm afraid not without creating and executing the Statement dynamically. With [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/library/ms188001.aspx) statement you can execute dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query:-

```
SELECT MAX(trans_date_np) AS column1, (SELECT MAX(trans_date_np) 
                                       FROM day_in_status_mcg 
                                       WHERE trans_date_np< SELECT MAX(trans_date_np) 
                                                            FROM day_in_status_mcg) AS column2
FROM day_in_status_mcg;
```

I hope this will solve your problem.